# How do I send a Blob object to the server? it keeps showing up empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I'm trying to send a Blob object to my server, which holds video, and then upload said image to my S3 storage, but currently I'm facing an issue, where the Blob comes as an empty object in my server.

```
      const blob = new Blob(videoChunks, { type: mimeType });
    
console.log(blob); //Blob {size: 47513, type: 'video/webm; codecs="opus,vp8"'}
            try {
              await axios.put(`/fulfill/${state.requestid}`, {
                state: state,
                celebReply: celebReply,
                blob:blob
              });
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(error);
            }
```

Despite the blob logging something on the client, in the server it just logs an empty array. How do I fix this?

I tried using `const formData = new FormData();` but I still kept getting an empty object in my server.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert Blob to File let

```
    const formData = new FormData()
    name let fileName = `${blob_file.name}.${blob_file.extension}`;
    file = new File([blob_file.blob], fileName);
    formData.append('file', file, fileName);
```

then send formData to server.